# WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 remove charset=UTF-8 from request

Tags: wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB 4.8.1, I recived a request at Proxy Service with following header:

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

When ESB sends the request to endpoint charset field has been removed.

How can I avoid that ESB removes that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to put next statements before send mediador:

```
<property name="messageType" value="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" scope="axis2"/>
```